Por una modificacion accidental de source/classpath mis clases dejaron de detectarse entre si
me surgió un problema con vscode y java que me impide seguir trabajando.
Antes mis proyectos tenían su carpeta propia, dentro de ella src contenía el main y las clases, interfaces, etc. necesario para que el proyecto funcione. Era posible ejecutar normalmente y todo se detectaba entre si.
Sin querer modifique algo del source path/class path/vscode (a esta altura ya no se cual fue) y ahora en todos mis proyectos me sale lo mismo:
"Nombre Clase cannot be resolved to a type" y "The declared package "" does not match the expected package "ruta.acceso.relativa""
ya intente varias cosas y nada funciona. Antes no me hacia falta declarar ningún paquete para manejar un proyecto y las clases se detectaban dentro de la misma carpeta src.
Si intento ejecutar:
"Could not find or load main class Nombre Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Nombre Main"
En la terminal de vscode parece que no llega a ejecutar el código, sino que se queda varias carpetas por detras, en mi caso se ve así:
PS C:\Users\xx\Documents\GitHub>
Sin embargo, el main de mis proyectos esta mas adelante en la ruta:
PS C:\Users\xx\Documents\GitHub\xx\xx\xx\xx\Carpeta de mi proyecto>
No se si tendrá algo que ver esto ultimo, pero con C++ no me da problemas y si llega al final de la ruta, ojala algún iluminado me salve.
Ya intente todas las "soluciones" típicas que gpt diría, necesito un milagro.

Sin más información es complicado ayudar. Supuestamente qué modificaste? Carga tus archivos tasks.json y launch.json

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! visual studio es otra cosa eh.. nada que ver con visual studio code...

En mi caso elimine una carpeta de mi workspace del sourcepath, se ve algo asi: from the project GitHub_587a8b48's source path y luego modifique los classpath, no tengo idea si hay un registro de como estaban antes o como deberia configurarlos para que funciones, ya agregue mi launch.json, no tengo ningun task.json y gracian bianchi por la aclaracion de vs y las guias, ya lo acomode

Seguí tocando cosas hasta que lo arregle solo ni se como, gracias por las correcciones

This question is similar to: JAVA | Could not find or load main class Main. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
